# Double click function not working in the React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, double-click

I have followed this link https://codesandbox.io/s/25777826onclick-works-but-ondoubleclick-is-ignored-on-react-component-ul6f5?file=/src/App.tsx to create a double-click event. This is simple and works. But if I use this method modification to my code is not working.

This one is a sample double-click function:

```html
const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    switch (e.detail) {
      case 1:
        console.log("click");
        break;
      case 2:
        console.log("double click");
        break;
      case 3:
        console.log("triple click");
        break;
    }
  };

<div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
```

This is my original code:

```html
const popUpHandler = e => {
    console.log('popUpHandler', e);
    if (e.type === 'Editor') {
      e.cancel = true;
      if (e.data.Id !== undefined) {
        getApptDetail(e.data.Id).then(response => {
          const doctorFromDb = response.data.doctor;
          if (doctorFromDb.includes('|')) {
            setStringOfDoctor(doctorFromDb.split('|'));
          } else {
            setStringOfDoctor([doctorFromDb]);
          }
          setAppt(response.data);
        });
        setOpenUpdatePopup(true);
      } else if (e.data.StartTime !== undefined) {
        setStringOfDoctor([]);
        setStartTime(e.data.StartTime);
        setDoctorName(e.data.Doctor);
        setOpenPopup(true);
      }
    }
    if (e.type === 'DeleteAlert') {
      e.cancel = true;
      if (e.data.Id !== undefined) {
        getApptDetail(e.data.Id).then(response => {
          setAppt(response.data);
        });
        setOpenDeletePopup(true);
      }
    }
    if (e.type === 'QuickInfo' && e.target.classList[0] === 'e-work-cells') {
      e.cancel = true;
      if (e.data.StartTime !== undefined) {
        setStringOfDoctor([]);
        setStartTime(e.data.StartTime);
        setDoctorName(e.data.Doctor);
        setOpenPopup(true);
      }
    }
  };
```

This one is after modification to my code, but is not working:

```html
const popUpHandler = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    switch (e.detail) {
      case 1:
        console.log('Nothing');
        break;
      case 2:
        if (e.type === 'Editor') {
      e.cancel = true;
      if (e.data.Id !== undefined) {
        getApptDetail(e.data.Id).then(response => {
          const doctorFromDb = response.data.doctor;
          if (doctorFromDb.includes('|')) {
            setStringOfDoctor(doctorFromDb.split('|'));
          } else {
            setStringOfDoctor([doctorFromDb]);
          }
          setAppt(response.data);
        });
        setOpenUpdatePopup(true);
      } else if (e.data.StartTime !== undefined) {
        setStringOfDoctor([]);
        setStartTime(e.data.StartTime);
        setDoctorName(e.data.Doctor);
        setOpenPopup(true);
      }
    }
    if (e.type === 'DeleteAlert') {
      e.cancel = true;
      if (e.data.Id !== undefined) {
        getApptDetail(e.data.Id).then(response => {
          setAppt(response.data);
        });
        setOpenDeletePopup(true);
      }
    }
    if (e.type === 'QuickInfo' && e.target.classList[0] === 'e-work-cells') {
      e.cancel = true;
      if (e.data.StartTime !== undefined) {
        setStringOfDoctor([]);
        setStartTime(e.data.StartTime);
        setDoctorName(e.data.Doctor);
        setOpenPopup(true);
      }
    }
    
    }
  };
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to modify my original code and make it double-click (case 2 is double click). Thank you.

Comment: Why don't just use `onDoubleClick`?

Comment: @Nick Can you show me how to use it?

Comment: on your button change `onClick={popUpHandler}` to `onDoubleClick={popUpHandler}` and use your original function (without the `switch(e.detail)` one)

Comment: Please reference  this link: https://dirask.com/posts/React-onDoubleClick-example-D9qQdD